# Use this custom adapter with volley android

Tags: android, adapter

I am working on an application in android. I have this code, and I tried to use it with volley so that I could load a json and add items to the list with the json, but I always end up doing it wrong...

```
package com.hmkcode.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

    //2. setListAdapter
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Item> generateData(){
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item("Item 1","First Item on the list"));
    items.add(new Item("Item 2","Second Item on the list"));
    items.add(new Item("Item 3","Third Item on the list"));

    return items;
}

}
```

I tried to implement it like this but the static item that i set inside onResponse doesnt show, plus when I try to click on the items, the app ends up crashing

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

    //2. setListAdapter
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Item> generateData(){
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item("Item 1","First Item on the list"));


    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://echo.jsontest.com/just/test/values/two";

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           //my loop here
             items.add(new Item("Item 1","this is just a sample "));
           }
 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    queue.add(jsObjRequest);


    return items;
}
```

EDIT:

```
    11-09 13:25:00.465:E/AndroidRuntime(10699): java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131230722, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.janime.MyAdapter)]
```

the app crashes when I click one of the items on the list after onResponse has been executed .
"Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread."

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? Can you show us the logcat?

Comment: 11-09 13:25:00.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10699): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131230722, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.janime.MyAdapter)]


the app crashes when I click one of the items on the list after onResponse has been executed .

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` when you get the response, parse the data and add it it to arraylist you should notify the adapter such that data set is changed!

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

    //2. setListAdapter
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Item> generateData(){
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item("Item 1","First Item on the list"));


    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://echo.jsontest.com/just/test/values/two";

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           //my loop here
             items.add(new Item("Item 1","this is just a sample "));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    queue.add(jsObjRequest);

    return items;
```